# Restricting column edits without restricting visibility

Tags: list, column

I've been using SharePoint for a while now but this is my first foray into a slightly more complex project. I'm trying to create a helpdesk ticketing system which is split into 3 separate lists.

**List 1 (initiator):** This stores no data but is used to generate the form which the user will be able to fill in to create a new ticket. Information from the form is pushed to list 2 upon creation of an item and the item is then deleted (ensuring the list is kept empty at all times).

**List 2 (admin console):** This one stores the data for each ticket and is only visible to support agents. Changes to items on this list (eg status updates, changes in agent assigned) need to be visible in list 3.

**List 3 (user console):** And here is where I run into trouble. List 3 is supposed to be a place where users can go to check the status of their ticket. I want them to be able to find out who the ticket was assigned to, get updates on it etc. But I also want them to be able to add additional information to the ticket here using a comments field. As a result, I want all the columns to be visible but only 1 column (comments) to be editable.

---

I've thought of a few ways around it but they're all a little messy. I could for example set up a workflow which is activated when an item in List 3 is edited. This would pull information from list 2 overwriting all columns except for comments. Effectively users would be unable to save changes if they make edits except to the comments column.

I've also googled around and found that using lookup columns may work, but I've been unable to get these working in list 3. When I try to point them to list 2, only a limited selection of lookup fields are available to me.

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

- Emma

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use one List containing all Ticket Items and work with Permissions. That would be alot easier :-)

You could make Listviews for normal users / agents so they see their tickets.

PS: I wanted to write this a comment but my reputation is too low :c

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I know how to create views but they always seem to allow the user to go into the item and see the full detail even when I only want to show them some.




Also I want to make sure that the end-user doesn't see any redundant columns (like "assigned to", "priority") on the form they fill in to send to us. Is that possible too?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but these requirements may need a bit of sharepoint modification through code. One way is creating own controltemplates via server side code. Another way would be the usage of javascript to hide elements on the client side.

Comment: There might also be 3rd Party solutions to hide columns based on permissions, here is a codeplex solution that does the job. https://sp2013columnpermission.codeplex.com/